# Custom routing in Codeigniter issue

Tags: codeigniter, routes

My url is like `base_url()/category/2`  , where 2 is the id of the category.

This is the content of my routes.php file:

```
$route['category/(:num)'] = "category/$1";
```

and this is the content of my controller:

```
class Category extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        echo 1; exit();
    }
}
```

when I access /category/2 I get 404 page instead of  **echo 1**;

Can someone tell me what am I missing ? thx

Answer (score 0):

In documentation is said after base_url() shouldn't go forward slash. It can be

```
base_url() . 'category/2';
```

or, prefered, as argument

```
base_url("category/2");
```

Secondly, you have to pass argument to `index($arg)` method, and your route would be

```
$route['category/(:num)'] = "category/index/$1";
```

Than, complete class would be

```
class Category extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index($arg = FALSE)
    {
        if ((int)$arg < 1)
        {
            echo 1;// check input and pass default category or put redirect
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            echo $arg;
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```